# Coproducts and Hochschild

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

I $\{X_i\}$ is a small family of associative $\mathbb{C}$-algebras and $X$ is their free product.

Then I have two questions:

1)  Why is $X$ their coproduct?

2)  Is the Hochschild homology of X isomorphic to the direct sum of the Hochschild homologies of the $X_i$?

IN both cases why or why not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hoschchild, the child of Hosch. For a picture, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Hochschild.

Comment: What have you tried? If you know the meaning of all terms,  1) is rather straightforward, really...

Comment: For 2) have you tried computing an example? Pick something simple, like the free product of a polynomial álgebra in one variable with itself, or the free product of k[x]/(x^2) with itself.